# The Redis SUBSCRIBE command stops the application

Tags: java, redis

I use the latest stable version of Redis and 3.0.1 (I also tried 2.8.1) client in Maven. The connection is good, if I change the address to a bad, then is error (good). This command works in the redis console. But if I use it in an application in a new thread or single use, it's a freezing application (zero error, but the application does not respond). Why is it not working? How to fix it?

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>redis.clients</groupId>
    <artifactId>jedis</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.1</version>
</dependency>
```

```
new Jedis("localhost", 6379, 10000).subscribe(new JedisPubSub() {
    @Override
    public void onMessage(String channel, String message) {
        System.out.println(channel + message);
    }

    @Override
    public void onPMessage(String pattern, String channel, String message) { }

    @Override
    public void onSubscribe(String channel, int subscribedChannels) { }

    @Override
    public void onUnsubscribe(String channel, int subscribedChannels) { }

    @Override
    public void onPUnsubscribe(String pattern, int subscribedChannels) { }

    @Override
    public void onPSubscribe(String pattern, int subscribedChannels) { }

}, "test");
```

Comment: Please show the exact commands which are causing the problem, both on the Redis console and from your Java code.  Speaking of which, are you using Jedis or some other Java library?

Comment: First try creating a new `Jedis` object via your call `new Jedis("localhost", 6379, 10000)`.  Play around with it, and make sure that it works.  You may check the Redis command line console to verify any commands you try.  Then, try calling `subscribe` from your Java code, in debug mode.  What happens?  Are there any error messages?

Comment: 1551793936.464448 [0 127.0.0.1:52434] "SUBSCRIBE" "test"